# ^= operator in vb.net (Xor Equals)?

Tags: operators, xor, c#-to-vb.net

Is there an equivalent in VB.NET to the C# ^= operator?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to code it like this:

```
A = A Xor B
```